# Cross-compile C++11/14 on CentOS for Windows

Tags: c++, centos, cross-compiling

I've set up a CentOS 6.5 box running jenkins, among other things, which I want to use for building a project I'm working on with a couple of friends. It's designed to run on Windows, as we all have windows.

The problem I'm having is that I haven't found a cross-compiler that works on CentOS. Everything I've seen only works on Debian-based distros, and the few that I've found that have been presented as "working on red hat" don't actually work, or their methods of acquisition don't seem viable anymore.

It would be preferable that it supports C++11, or even C++14, as a couple of the guys I'm working on it with haven't ever delved into anything before C++11 and they're "scared of relearning half of what they know."

Everything I've searched for about MinGW or cross-compiling on CentOS has led to a dead end. Am I better off scrapping the installation and installing something debian-based like ubuntu server, or is there a cross-compiler that actually works to compile for windows on redhat distros?

Answer (score 0):

You can use g++ C++ 11. For this you need to install it on your centOS machine. The installation procedure can be found on the following link - [Install g++ C++ 11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63587/how-to-install-g-4-7-2-c11-on-centos-5-x). I have been using this and it works fine.